# Highlight radio button on pageload

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, radio-button, pageload, cfml

I have one radio button at the top of the page to show 'No Chosen Supplier' and then several other radio buttons within a query loop.

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="nosupp" name="supp" onchange="resetSupp(this);">
  No Supplier Chosen
</label>

<cfloop query="supplier"
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="chk1" name="supp" value="#supplier.id#" onchange="change(this);" <cfif getChosen.RecordCount>checked="Yes"</cfif>>
    Chosen Supplier
  </label>
</cfloop>
```

So I have submitted the form containing these buttons and the button that is checked is stored in the database.

I then query the database to check if the radio button value is 'true', using getChosen.RecordCount.

The problem I am having is that the getChosen.RecordCount selects the right radio button, but without the red highlighting that I am using.

Here is how I am highlighting the buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function change(obj) {
  var tr=obj.parentNode.parentNode;
  var tbl = tr.parentNode.parentNode;
  var inputs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++)
  inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
  tr.style.backgroundColor=(obj.checked)? 'red' : 'transparent';
}

function resetSupp(obj) {
  var tr=obj.parentNode.parentNode;
  var tbl = tr.parentNode.parentNode;
  var inputs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++)
  inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
  tr.style.backgroundColor= 'transparent';
}
</script>
```

How do I get the button that is set to 'true' in the database to have the highlighting on page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your function written, but it sounds as though you never call it to initialize everything once the page is loaded.

To follow best practices, you want to call `change(obj)` when `body.onload` is completed. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load) go over some different ways of doing this.

The easiest/most reliable (imo) is using jQuery, but it doesn't appear that you're using it. The next best (again, imo) is to use the `document.onload=function` declaration.

Unless there is only one input you need to initialize, you'll probably want to write another function which actually loops through each of the inputs and calls `change(obj)`. You'll then call your new `init()` function when `body.onload` fires.

So, you would have

```
document.onload=init
```

and

```
function init(){
    // loop through all your inputs
    // call change(obj) on each one
}
```

**edit** I just re-read your changeObj and noticed that you're passing in an element and backing up the DOM tree using parentNode, so you're already looping through each input, so my pseudocode for `init` would be a little off as it stands. Though, I would have probably used getElementsByName and passed in the name of the input group so you're not resetting every input every time `change(obj)` is called.